# How to show that $L_p(\mu)_+$ is not solid (i.e., $L_p(\mu)_+$ has empty interior)?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a probability space.

Let $L_p (\mu)$ with fixed $p \geq 1$ be defined to be the collection of all ($\mu$- equivalence classes of) Borel measurable functions $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $\int_{\Omega} |f|^{p} \mathrm{d} \mu < \infty$. 
Denote by $L_p (\mu)_+$ the positive cone of $L_p (\mu)$.

We say that a subset $E$ of an ordered Banach space (or a Banach lattice) is **solid** if $E$ contains at least one interior point.

When I read some textbook, it states that "the positive cone $L_p(\mu)_+$ is not solid". Therefore, I'm struggling to figure out how to verify this statement and is this statement always true for any $p \geq 1$? Could anyone help me out please?

If it is convenient to set $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, please feel free to do it then.

Sincerely appreciate your comment or idea in advance!

Comment: Probably a good idea to define positive cone.

Comment: Do you mean the functions that are ae. non negative?

Comment: @copper.hat For the case of the positive cone of $L_p$ space, the functions are non-negative a.e.. While in the case for $bc(\Omega)_+$, the functions are non-negative.

Comment: You need more conditions. If you take $\Omega = \{1,...,n\}$ and $\mu$ the uniform measure then the positive cone has a non empty interior.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat. What if we take $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ be some Gaussian distribution, then does $L_p(\mu)_+$ have a non-empty interior? Could you give me some idea or hint to show whether it contains a non-empty interior? Many thanks again

Comment: Let $t_n(x) = n \max(0,n -n^3 x)$, note that $\int t_n \to 0$. Then if $f$ is bounded the function $f-t_n$ must be negative on a set of positive measure for sufficiently large $n$. The bounded functions are dense in $L_p (\mu)$ hence no element of this positive cone can be an interior point.

Comment: I got it, many thanks again @copper.hat. And enlightened by your comments, I think the positive cone $bc(\mathbb{R})_+$ should be solid. Am I right? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Let assume $\Omega = N$,sequence of natural number, then we are dealing with ${l^p}$. Let $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_n > 0 $ for all $n$ is an interior point. And take $\lambda >0$ such that $x+y \in l^P_+$ for all $|| y  || = \lambda$. There is such a positive $\lambda$ since $x$ is an interior point of $l^p_+$. Let $n$ is large enough such that $x_n < \lambda$. Now define $a= -\lambda e_n$ then $||a|| = \lambda$ but $x+a \notin l^P_+$ since its n-th component is negative! which is a contradiction .